# How to check if an object from an array has a specific format

Tags: javascript

So i have an array of objects named: `tokens`. Each object from this array has this format: `{tokenName: string}`. I want to test if each element from this array has the exact same format or else throw an error.

I have tried this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
          if (
            typeof tokens[i].tokenName === "string" &&
            tokens[i].hasOwnProperty("tokenName")
          ) {
            // do stuff
          } else {
            throw new Error("Invalid array format");
 }
```

But it won't pass the test.

Comment: hasOwnProperty - you’re missing a T

Comment: Well what *exactly* goes wrong? What happens that you don't expect?

Comment: If I pass an array with that specific format, it throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to iterate over the array of objects, and apply the test to each object.

In this example `tokens1` all objects have the `tokenName` key, and all are strings. `tokens2` has one value that is an integer. `tokens3` has a `tokenAge` key.

```js
const tokens1=[{tokenName:"name1"},{tokenName:"name2"},{tokenName:"name3"},{tokenName:"name4"}],tokens2=[{tokenName:"name1"},{tokenName:"name2"},{tokenName:9},{tokenName:"name4"}],tokens3=[{tokenName:"name1"},{tokenName:"name2"},{tokenAge:"name3"},{tokenName:"name4"}];

// Accept an array of objects
function checkTokenName(tokens) {
  
  // Check the every token object in the
  // array passes the condition - true if it
  // does, false if it doesn't
  return tokens.every(token => {
    return (
      token.hasOwnProperty('tokenName')
      && typeof token.tokenName === 'string'
    );
  });
}

console.log(checkTokenName(tokens1));
console.log(checkTokenName(tokens2));
console.log(checkTokenName(tokens3));
```

Answer (score 1):

hasOwnProperty is misspelled .
Also the if condition should first check the property if it exists and then check typeof like

```
tokens[i].hasOwnProperty("tokenName") &&
typeof tokens[i].tokenName === "string"
```